# Strangely, two lines work after SECOND click of toggle hide/show button not FIRST click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, toggle

Everything works perfectly after the SECOND click of toggle button. Some lines work as they should on FIRST click so I know the if and else content is being entered. Please see code comments for a better understanding. Where is my logic wrong, causing these two lines not to work after the FIRST click? Even if you do not know exactly the problem, would like any ideas of what could be causing this.

```
   function toggleView(switchImgTag) {
        var cnt = 0;
        var but = document.getElementById("but_Toggle");
        while (cnt <= 5000) { 
            window['ele' + cnt] = document.getElementById('camimg' + cnt);
            window['imageEle' + cnt] = document.getElementById('camimg' + cnt);
            if (window['ele' + cnt].style.display == "block") {
             but.innerHTML = "Thumbs"; //Strangely, executes after "second" click of List button
             window['ele' + cnt].style.display = "none"; //Strangely, executes after "second" click of List button
             document.getElementById('im' + cnt).style.width = '20px'; //Executes after very first click of List button as it should
             document.getElementById('im' + cnt).style.visibility = 'visible'; //Executes after very first click of List button as it should
         }
         else { 
             but.innerHTML = "List";
             window['ele' + cnt].style.display = "block";
             document.getElementById('im' + cnt).style.width = '1px'; //Executes after first click of List button as it should
             document.getElementById('im' + cnt).style.visibility = 'hidden'; //Executes after very first click of List button as it should
         }
         cnt++;
        }
    }
```

Then I have the button..

```
<button id="but_Toggle" type="button" onclick="javascript:toggleView();">List</button>
```

Then I have the content being controlled...

```
 retstr.AppendLine("<img alt ='" & streamref & "'")
    retstr.AppendLine(" title ='" & Trim(image_title_with_PTZ) & " - " & streamref & "'")
    retstr.AppendLine(" src = '" & imgsrc & "'")
    retstr.AppendLine(" class = 'item'")

    If searchbar = False Then
        retstr.AppendLine(" id = 'camimg" & count & "'")
    Else
        retstr.AppendLine(" id = 'camimg" & count & "'")
    End If

    retstr.AppendLine(" ondblclick = ""javascript:window.open('" & imgsrc & "')""")
    'retstr.AppendLine("  data-streamurl='" & "rtsp://127.0.0.1/cam.stream" & "'")
    retstr.Append("/></div>")
    retstr.AppendLine("<div class='preview'")
    retstr.AppendLine(" title ='" & Trim(image_title_with_PTZ) & " - " & streamref & "'")
    retstr.AppendLine(" id = '" & imgsrc & "'")
    retstr.AppendLine(">")
    retstr.Append("<div class=imagename><img alt ='" & streamref & "' title ='" & Trim(image_title_with_PTZ) & " - " & streamref & "'" & " id='im" & count & "' src='../images/cam.png' height=20 class=item2  ondblclick =javascript:window.open('" & imgsrc & "')><font size=1><a href='" & imgsrc & "'>" & image_title_with_PTZ & "</a></font></nb></span></div></div>")
```

Comment: Do the `document.getElementById('camimg' + cnt);` elements have a display value already?  If not, once set you would see the if/else working properly.

Comment: Those images with id ('camimg' + cnt) displays initially. Then I have to click that toggle button twice for those image to hide and show correctly which works correctly thereafter. It is only from the beginning that I have to click the toggle button TWICE. But then works/toggles with single click events thereafter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the display explicitly, this is the style's display, not whether it displays or not.
So after the line :

retstr.AppendLine(" class = 'item'")

add the following line

retstr.AppendLine(" style = 'display:block'")